# How to take mean,std and mad of multiple dataframes that are appended in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've several hundred dataframes that are appended in a list. All the dataframes have same number of columns but the number of rows are not same. The column names are also same.

So i want to take the mean, mad, std of column value of each column and i'm doing something like this:

All the dataframes are appended in a list (lst)

```
lst = []


for filen, filen1 in zip(filelistn, filelist1):
   df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
   df2 = pd.read_table(path_to_files1+filen1, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

   dfs = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='wave', how='inner')
   dfs = df1 - df2
   lst.append(dfs)

df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'wave',how='outer'), lst)
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]).T 
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(['mean','std','mad','median']).T
```

But the results that i'm getting are a bit weird, Like in column `mad` there are values like `21,65,36` which is absurd.

```
        wave       mean    median        mad
0    4050.32  -0.016182 -0.011940   0.008885
1    4208.98   0.023707  0.007189   0.032585
2    4374.94  -0.001321 -0.001196   0.000378
3    4379.74   0.002778  0.003380   0.004685
4    6828.60 -10.604568 -0.000590  21.084799
5    6839.84  -0.003466 -0.001870   0.010169
6    6842.04 -32.751551 -0.002514  65.118329
7    6842.69  18.293519 -0.002158  36.385884
```

The column `wave` is same in all the dataframes, but the number of rows are not. Does it has anything to do with that? May be it's taking the mean of the wrong rows?

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: could you please add a simplified code which could be tested?

Comment: done.! That's what i'm doing. @PEBKAC

Comment: perhaps you could just recreate the two dataframes with a few (7) rows and the used columns? So df1 = ... , df2 =...  Like this is quite difficult to ascertain the error ... wish I could help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.concat` to concatenate the sequence of data frames into one large data frame and calculate the statistics afterwards like so.

```
import pandas as pd

# lst = [construct list of dataframes ...]
df = pd.concat(lst, axis=0)
means = df.mean()
stds = df.std()
```

Edit: if you would like to get the statistics broken down by some key, e.g. `wave`, you can use the following.

```
means = df.groupby('wave').mean()
```

Comment: That's not what i want to do. I want the mean, std and mad of each column value.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to calculate statistics for each column conditional on the value in `wave`?

Comment: yes but i've tried this, i'm getting some really absurd values for some of the rows and i don't understand why.

Comment: @astroluv, added an edit above that should achieve the desired result.